# how to make client server program to continuously run

Tags: java, java-server, java-client

I am creating a Java a simple client/server program although both are just working fine. The problem is that when the client or the server encountered an error it will stop. Is there a way for my client/server app to continuously run even if it encounters an error?

Comment: `try`/`catch` must help you :)

Comment: Can you add some source code? Have you thought of running each in separate thread?

Comment: I haven't tried threads yet any sample code you can give?

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code in a loop and catch any exceptions inside your loop. e.g.

```
while (true) {
    try {
    //Do what ever your server does
    } catch (Exception e) {
    //Log your exception to a log file
    }
}
```